# Insert variable to array using .push() based on outcome of conditional statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have a script that includes a for-loop that generates the numbers 0-9. The script also includes a function that checks if the numbers generated by the for-loop are divisible by 3 or 5. If they are divisible (e.g. 9 is divisible by 3), the if/else-statement returns true, and if they are not divisible, the conditional-statement returns false.

What I want to achieve is that, when the conditional statement returns true, the number should be added to an empty array.

The desired result would in this case be:

```
var myArray = [0, 3, 5, 6, 9];
```

This is my current code:

```
var isDivisibleArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    isMultiple(i);
}

function isMultiple() {

    var isMultipleOf3 = i % 3;
    var isMultipleOf5 = i % 5;

    if(isMultipleOf3 === 0 || isMultipleOf5 === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }

}

isMultiple();
```

I am using the modulus operator to find out if a number is divisible with 3 or 5, since if x % 3 = 0, x is divisible with 3, as an example.

I have done some experimenting as well. If I do this is the for-loop, I can manage to print the outcome using an alert:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alert(isMultiple(i));
}
```

The outcome is T, F, F, T, F, T, T, F, F, T.

I have also tried this approach within the conditional statement:

```
if(isMultipleOf3 === 0 || isMultipleOf5 === 0) {
    isDivisibleArray.push(i);
}
```

This has not succeeded. All help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why are you calling isMultiple() in the end?

Comment: To invoke the function, or else it won't run, right?

Comment: sidenote: change the order. first the biggest 5 and then 3

Comment: Why are you calling another function? Why don't you do it directly? https://jsfiddle.net/r2vbgm33/ Or, if you want just the array of numbers: https://jsfiddle.net/r2vbgm33/1/ Also, regarding the first comment, you're calling the function in the loop. You don't need to call it again at the end.

Comment: Side note, you are not recieving `i` inside the function as a parameter

Comment: Note that your function should have an input argument: `function isMultiple(i) {...} `, otherwise some hidden bugs may appear later.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var isDivisibleArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(isMultiple(i)) {
      isDivisibleArray.push(i);
    }
}

function isMultiple(i) {
    return i % 5 === 0 || i % 3 === 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a separate function.  Furthermore the following:

```
if(isMultipleOf3 === 0 || isMultipleOf5 === 0) {
    return true;
}

else {
    return false;
}
```

Can simply be written:

```
return isMultipleOf3 === 0 || isMultipleOf5 === 0;
```

The entire solution is as simple as follows:

```
var isDivisibleArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i%3 === 0 || i%5 === 0) isDivisibleArray.push(i);
}

console.log(isDivisibleArray); //[ 0, 3, 5, 6, 9 ]
```

Comment: true, but keeping isMultiple as a function keeps it open to extension

Comment: @AyushGupta That's in violation of the YAGNI principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it and a particularly egregious one at that considering it's one line of code

Comment: I'd prefer to go by SOLID principles, specifically Dependency inversion principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: If you keep isMultiple as a function, the `if` only knows that isMutliple should return a truthy value, and doest care about the logic

Comment: @AyushGupta You are *way* over-engineering this---p.s. not responding anymore

Comment: Maybe for this small use case. But I like to go by some rules of thumb, and mostly delegate logic to different functions. Also, O'm trying to make a habit of that.

Answer (score -1):

The error is that you aren't actually pushing to the array, only calling the function to check - but then you ignore the result.

You could make this code shorter and reusable by putting it inside a function that you can call with different parameters

```js
function createArray(min = 0, max = 9, divisibleBy = [3, 5]) {
  return [...Array(max + 1).keys()]
    .filter(e => e >= min && divisibleBy.some(i => e % i === 0))
}

console.log(createArray());
// same as createArray(0, 9, [3, 5])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    let isDivisibleArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if(isMultiple(i)=== true){  
  isDivisibleArray.push(i)
}
}

function isMultiple(i) {

    var isMultipleOf3 = i % 3;
    var isMultipleOf5 = i % 5;

    if(isMultipleOf3 === 0 || isMultipleOf5 === 0) {

      return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

try this